# MongoId is not updating model data also it does not show any error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I have two systems that used to work on the AWS platform using the mongo version 3.4.16. Currently, I moved them to the GCP and for that reason, I'm using the newer mongo version 4.2.8.
The first thing you should keep in mind is that these systems had been working for many years before I changed their servers. Both are using the same mongo server also the same collection and credentials. So here is the problem:

The problematic system is able to consult and create data on MongoDB, but it isn't able to update any attribute of any model. I tried to update an attribute running this application using the web interface also running on rails console and it has the same problem. I didn't change any thing else than the mongo version.

```
:023 > user = User.where({email: 'email@test.com'}).first
:024 > user.name
 => "user name"
:025 > user.name = "new user name"
 => "new user name"
:026 > user.save!
 [paperclip] Saving attachments.
  => true
:027 > user = User.where({email: 'email@test.com'}).first
:028 > user.name
 => "user name"
```

The second system has the same gem version (when I'm talking about the MongoDB gems) and it is still working (updating the model attributes) even changing the mongo version from the 3.4.16 version to the 4.2.8 one (as I mentioned before). Do you have any idea about what could happen?

The problematic system Gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.22.5)
actionpack (3.2.22.5)
activemodel (3.2.22.5)
activerecord (3.2.22.5)
activeresource (3.2.22.5)
activesupport (3.2.22.5)
addressable (2.5.0)
akami (1.3.1)
apipie-rails (0.3.7)
arel (3.0.3)
aws-sdk (1.66.0)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
better_errors (2.1.1)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
bson (4.3.0, 1.12.5)
bson_ext (1.12.5)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (default: 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capybara (2.12.0)
client_side_validations (3.2.8)
cocaine (0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
connection_pool (2.2.1)
cpf_cnpj (0.3.0)
credit_card_validations (3.4.0)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-rails (1.4.5)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
daemons (1.2.6)
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
devise (3.5.10)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
domain_name (0.5.20161129)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.2)
execjs (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.6.0)
faraday (0.11.0)
faraday_middleware (0.11.0.1)
faye-websocket (0.10.0)
figaro (1.1.1)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
geocoder (1.3.3)
gherkin (4.0.0)
google-geocode (1.2.1)
google_maps_service (0.4.2)
gyoku (1.3.1)
hike (1.2.3)
hiredis (0.6.1)
hoe (3.16.0)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
httparty (0.13.3)
httpi (2.4.2)
hurley (0.2)
i18n (0.9.5)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
json (1.8.6, default: 1.8.3)
libv8 (3.16.14.19 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.5.5)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.11.3, 5.8.3)
momentjs-rails (2.17.1)
mongo (2.6.2)
mongo_session_store-rails3 (6.0.0)
mongoid (3.1.7)
mongoid-geospatial (4.0.0)
mongoid-paperclip (0.0.11)
mongoid_userstamp (0.4.0)
moped (1.5.3)
multi_json (1.13.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
multi_xml (0.6.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-http-persistent (1.9)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.11.0)
newrelic_mongodb (0.1.2)
newrelic_rpm (3.18.1.330)
nokogiri (1.6.6.4)
nori (2.6.0)
origin (1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (3.1.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
power_assert (1.0.1, 0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
puma (3.12.0)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (1.4.7)
rack-cache (1.9.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (3.2.22.5)
railties (3.2.22.5)
rake (12.0.0, 10.4.2)
rc-rest (4.0)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1, 3.12.2)
redis (3.3.3)
redis-objects (1.2.1)
ref (2.0.0)
responders (1.1.2)
rest-client (2.0.0)
retriable (2.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.23)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
savon (2.11.1)
socksify (1.7.1)
sprockets (2.2.3)
test-unit (3.2.3, 3.1.5)
therubyracer (0.12.3)
thin (1.7.2)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.52)
uglifier (3.0.4)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
warden (1.2.7)
wasabi (3.5.0)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
will_paginate (3.1.5)
will_paginate_mongoid (2.0.1)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

The Working system Gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.22.5)
actionpack (3.2.22.5)
activemodel (3.2.22.5)
activerecord (3.2.22.5)
activeresource (3.2.22.5)
activesupport (3.2.22.5)
addressable (2.5.2, 2.5.0)
adminlte2-rails (0.0.6)
akami (1.3.1)
apipie-rails (0.3.7)
arel (3.0.3)
autoprefixer-rails (8.2.0)
aws-sdk (1.67.0, 1.66.0)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.67.0, 1.66.0)
backports (3.11.1)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
better_errors (2.4.0, 2.1.1)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
bson (4.3.0, 1.12.5)
bson_ext (1.12.5)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (default: 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capybara (2.18.0, 2.12.0)
chartkick (2.3.3)
client_side_validations (3.2.8)
climate_control (0.2.0)
cocaine (0.6.0, 0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5, 1.0.5)
connection_pool (2.2.2, 2.2.1)
cpf_cnpj (0.4.1, 0.3.0)
credit_card_validations (3.5.0, 3.4.0)
cucumber (3.1.0, 2.4.0)
cucumber-core (3.1.0, 1.5.0)
cucumber-expressions (5.0.14)
cucumber-rails (1.4.5)
cucumber-tag_expressions (1.1.1)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
daemons (1.2.6)
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
declarative (0.0.10)
declarative-option (0.1.0)
devise (3.5.10)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
domain_name (0.5.20170404, 0.5.20161129)
dropzonejs-rails (0.8.2)
erubi (1.7.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.7, 1.2.2)
execjs (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.6.0)
faraday (0.12.2, 0.11.0)
faraday_middleware (0.12.2, 0.11.0.1)
faye-websocket (0.10.0)
fcm (0.0.2)
ffi (1.9.23)
figaro (1.1.1)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
geocoder (1.3.3)
gherkin (5.0.0, 4.0.0)
google-api-client (0.10.3)
google-geocode (1.2.1)
google_maps_service (0.4.2)
googleauth (0.6.2)
gyoku (1.3.1)
hike (1.2.3)
hiredis (0.6.1)
hoe (3.16.0)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
httparty (0.13.3)
httpclient (2.8.3)
httpi (2.4.3, 2.4.2)
hurley (0.2)
i18n (0.9.5)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
jquery_mask_rails (0.1.0)
json (1.8.6, default: 1.8.3)
jwt (1.5.6)
libv8 (3.16.14.19 x86_64-linux)
little-plugger (1.1.4)
logging (2.2.2)
mail (2.5.5)
memoist (0.16.0)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_mime (1.0.0)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
minitest (5.11.3, 5.8.3)
momentjs-rails (2.20.1, 2.17.1)
mongo (2.6.2)
mongo_session_store-rails3 (6.0.0)
mongoid (3.1.7)
mongoid-geospatial (4.0.0)
mongoid-paperclip (0.0.11)
mongoid_userstamp (0.4.0)
moped (1.5.3)
multi_json (1.13.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
multi_xml (0.6.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-http-persistent (1.9)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.11.0)
newrelic_mongodb (0.1.2)
newrelic_rpm (5.3.0.346, 3.18.1.330)
nokogiri (1.8.2, 1.6.6.4)
nori (2.6.0)
origin (1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
os (0.9.6)
pagarme (2.2.2)
pagy (3.4.1)
paperclip (3.1.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
power_assert (1.1.1, 1.0.1, 0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
public_suffix (3.0.2, 2.0.5)
puma (3.12.0, 3.11.3)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (1.4.7)
rack-cache (1.9.0, 1.8.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (3.2.22.5)
railties (3.2.22.5)
rake (12.3.1, 12.0.0, 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.10)
rc-rest (4.0)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1, 3.12.2)
redis (4.0.1, 3.3.3)
redis-objects (1.4.0, 1.2.1)
ref (2.0.0)
representable (3.0.4)
responders (1.1.2)
rest-client (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
retriable (2.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.5.6, 3.4.23)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
savon (2.12.0, 2.11.1)
signet (0.8.1)
socksify (1.7.1)
sprockets (2.2.3)
terrapin (0.6.0)
test-unit (3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.5)
therubyracer (0.12.3)
thin (1.7.2)
thor (0.20.0, 0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6, 0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
time_difference (0.5.0)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.54, 0.3.52)
uber (0.1.0)
uglifier (3.2.0, 3.0.4)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.5, 0.0.7.2)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
warden (1.2.7)
wasabi (3.5.0)
websocket-driver (0.7.0, 0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.3, 0.1.2)
will_paginate (3.1.6, 3.1.5)
will_paginate_mongoid (2.0.1)
xpath (3.0.0, 2.0.0)
```

I Have never seen anything like that before.

Answer (score 0):

Use [command monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring) to determine/verify what commands are being sent and to what database.

Inspect collections via mongo shell to verify their contents before and after the update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however that system currently does not support this feature, and part of the problem is that I can't update the system gems because I would need to update all of them also language features and it isn't possible (I had tried before I asked about this problem here)

app/models/command__log_subscriber.rb:2:in `<class:CommandLogSubscriber>': uninitialized constant CommandLogSubscriber::Mongo (NameError)

Comment: That sounds like some kind of a dependency issue.

Comment: In any event, driver 2.6 supports command monitoring, so it should work one way or another.